Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core
I'm using amplify to push my lambda. When I run it locally via amplify mock function {functionName} it runs and behaves as expected. When I deploy using amplify push it successfully deploys. However when I attempt to run the lambda from the AWS lambda ui I get the following error message.
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}

My development machine is a mac using the M3 chip. Python is version 3.8.19. I'm stuck and thus far nothing I've been able to find online has resolved my issue.
